# Excel VBA to Assign Border to a group based on Column name and Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code and I want to do the following:

Go through a specific column based on its name (example "Company") and to change the border based on the values in that column (example "CompanyA","CompanyB", "CompanyC" etc.) to be Thick Box Border. This means "Company A" (50 rows) would get a border and "Company B" (5 rows) would get a border and so on.

Can this be done? Ty in advance!

```
Sub DrawBorders() 

Dim rCell As Range 
Dim rRange As Range 

Set rRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)) 

For Each rCell In rRange 
    If Not IsEmpty(rCell) And _ 
    Not IsEmpty(rCell.Offset(1, 0)) Then 
        With rCell 
            If .Value <> .Offset(1, 0).Value Then 
                With .EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous 
                    .Weight = xlMedium 
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 
                End With 
            End If 
        End With 
    End If 
Next rCell 

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want a different border for each company? Or just a border if it has a name?

Comment: A Border for each company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adjusted my code to fit your request. This will only put borders around desired company types. You may need to add further error catching to the IF-Statements depending on your data you're processing.

```
Sub DrawBoarders()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim Prev As String
    Dim MyCell As String
    Prev = ""

    Set rRange = Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    Dim SpecificCompany(3) As String 'Using 3 companies (Company A, B, & C)
    'Array of desired company names
    SpecificCompany(0) = "CompanyA"
    SpecificCompany(1) = "CompanyB"
    SpecificCompany(2) = "CompanyC"


    If IsInArray(Range("A1"), SpecificCompany) Then 'Check 1st row
            With Range("A1").EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
    End If

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If IsInArray(rCell.Value, SpecificCompany) And rCell.Value <> rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            With rCell.EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell) And _
        Not IsEmpty(rCell.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        If rCell.Value <> rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            With rCell.EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Brad, ty for the answer, but this doesnt let me select which ones by column and name get the boarder -- I am trying to highlight company A, Company B and Company C from Company D,E,F etc. and the code above does all companies

Comment: Why have you decided to use borders? Would highlighting work as well? It would be less processing to find both the starting and end point of a company type & or could use conditional formatting.

Comment: Hello, yes it is a requirement to be borders which I know is not ideal

Comment: Works Great! ty so much